# What is トンガリイボザル?

Tags: meaning

```
ま、わたしのカンペキな説明なら、
2才のトンガリイボザルだって
理解120％だけどね！
```

Is it sharp-minded colobus or colobus with something pointy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とんがり＝とがった、尖った＝pointed＝something that is long and its edge is very sharp, typically "circular cone."

いぼ＝疣=verruca

サル=monkey

トンガリイボザル＝とがったいぼを持つサル＝the monkey with the coned verruca(s)

This is an imaginary animal, which is created by the writer, who seems to have created a lot of other imaginary animals as well.

イボイノシシ, however, is a real animal that has four verrucas in its face.

http://wonder.whdpet.com/p/1703/CJMocx6Y1.html

イボ＝verrucas, 
イノシシ＝a wild pig